# Select lowest ID in selection if qualifier is not met

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that pulls a single record based on the type of document.  I need to change that to pull either the lowest value of the ID column for a particular 'case' or if the document type is 'Deed'.  There can be multiple 'Deed' records and we need all of them. Currently it pulls only 'primary deed'. How would I go about this?

```
SELECT        
    DocIDKey, CaseNumberKey, Grantee, Grantor, 
    DocID, DocDate, RecDate, PrimaryDocID, RelatedDocID, 
    Interest, DocAmt, DocPath, DocType
FROM            
    Documents
WHERE        
    (CaseNumberKey = @CaseNumberKey) 
    AND (DocType = 'Deed')
```

Comment: Show your expected output for both scenarios. You want either 1 record returned for the case or all the records for a certain deed?

Comment: What is ID and just how is that the the primary deed?  VTC

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide Sample data as ddl+dml and desired results.

Comment: Absolutely need sample data and expected result

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question's a bit confusing. You say you need it to pull either the lowest case number, OR anything with a DocType of 'Deed', but the query you show is actually of anything with the requested case number, AND having a DocType of 'Deed.' And it doesn't look at minimums at all? And what is the 'primary deed,' and what does @CaseNumberKey come from? Is that a parameter passed to an inline function or procedure, or is it calculated based on something earlier on?

Going from what it sounds like you want, assuming you're running 2008 or over, check out the OVER clause, and also the MIN function. Something like the following, maybe?

```
SELECT        
    DocIDKey, CaseNumberKey, Grantee, Grantor, 
    DocID, DocDate, RecDate, PrimaryDocID, RelatedDocID, 
    Interest, DocAmt, DocPath, DocType
FROM            
    (SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CaseNumberKey ORDER BY DocIDKey ASC) AS Row_Num, 
        DocIDKey, CaseNumberKey, Grantee, Grantor, 
        DocID, DocDate, RecDate, PrimaryDocID, RelatedDocID, 
        Interest, DocAmt, DocPath, DocType
    FROM Documents 
    WHERE CaseNumberKey = @CaseNumberKey AND DocType = 'Deed') sub
WHERE Row_Num = 1
```

This should give you the row associated with the lowest DocIDKey value, where the CaseNumberKey = the value provided, and DocType = 'Deed.' Basically, what it does is it first (in the subquery) sorts everything by DocIDKey and gives each row a Row_Number according to the sort, and then filters for just the first of the sorted rows.

(Note: the "PARTITION BY CaseNumberKey" part is optional, since you're already filtering by CaseNumberKey).

EDIT: Modified version (after seeing the comment below):

```
SELECT        
    DocIDKey, CaseNumberKey, Grantee, Grantor, 
    DocID, DocDate, RecDate, PrimaryDocID, RelatedDocID, 
    Interest, DocAmt, DocPath, DocType
FROM            
    (SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CaseNumberKey ORDER BY DocIDKey ASC) AS Row_Num, 
        DocIDKey, CaseNumberKey, Grantee, Grantor, 
        DocID, DocDate, RecDate, PrimaryDocID, RelatedDocID, 
        Interest, DocAmt, DocPath, DocType
    FROM Documents 
    WHERE CaseNumberKey = @CaseNumberKey) sub
WHERE Row_Num = 1
UNION SELECT 
    DocIDKey, CaseNumberKey, Grantee, Grantor, 
    DocID, DocDate, RecDate, PrimaryDocID, RelatedDocID, 
    Interest, DocAmt, DocPath, DocType
FROM Documents
WHERE CaseNumberKey = @CaseNumberKey AND DocType = 'Deed'
```

^ This should give you the first document (the document with the lowest DocIDKey), plus all documents of type 'Deed,' for the specified CaseNumberKey.

Comment: I didn't really know where to start with the sub query so I gave the query we used prior. There is a 'primary deed' among other document designations and we used to use just 'primary deed' but there are times when 'primary deed' is not the right document (less than 1%) so we need the 1st document added to the case or all the documents designated as 'deed' are listed on the report in case there is a tangled title and multiple 'deeds' control a property.

Comment: Ok... I _think_ I understand. :) I've added a new version - this one should give you the first document (assuming the first document is the one with the lowest DocIDKey), plus all documents of type, "Deed," for the specified CaseNumberKey.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly.  I did have to make a stored procedure due to SSRS not allowing the use of the OVER clause but it works perfectly.